# Object/factory with type XXXX is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this ThemeCubit class where I have annotated it as Injectable.

```
@Injectable()
class ThemeCubit extends Cubit<bool> {
  ISharedPreference prefs;
  ThemeCubit(this.prefs) : super(false);
}
```

then i have run the build_runner command (`flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`)
and I can clearly see it has been generated inside the GetIt code below.

```
extension GetItInjectableX on _i1.GetIt {
  // initializes the registration of main-scope dependencies inside of GetIt
  Future<_i1.GetIt> init({
    String? environment,
    _i2.EnvironmentFilter? environmentFilter,
  }) async {
    final gh = _i2.GetItHelper(
      this,
      environment,
      environmentFilter,
    );
    final registureModules = _$RegistureModules();
    gh.lazySingleton<_i3.Dio>(() => registureModules.dio());
    gh.factory<_i4.GlobalConfiguration>(() => _i4.GlobalConfiguration());
    await gh.factoryAsync<_i5.SharedPreferences>(
      () => registureModules.sharedPreferences,
      preResolve: true,
    );
    gh.factory<_i6.ISharedPreference>(
        () => _i7.SharedPreference(gh<_i5.SharedPreferences>()));
    gh.factory<_i8.ThemeCubit>(
        () => _i8.ThemeCubit(gh<_i6.ISharedPreference>()));
    return this;
  }
}

class _$RegistureModules extends _i9.RegistureModules {}
```

Now i am trying to access the class using getIT() but it says ThemeCubit is not registered inside GetIt.

anyone know of any solution?